# "maturin build" fails on Windows

Tags: python, rust

When I run `maturin build` on Windows I get the following error message:

```
 Found pyo3 bindings
 Found CPython 3.8 at C:\Python\_envs\Python38\python.exe, CPython 3.7 at C:\Python\_envs\Python37\python.exe
 maturin failed
  Caused by: Failed to build source distribution
  Caused by: Failed to add file from Cargo.toml.orig to sdist as Cargo.toml.orig
  Caused by: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (os error 2) when getting metadata for Cargo.toml.orig
```

On Linux the command succeeds.
On Windows I've:

- setup the Python environments
- installed pip package maturin
- Rust version is rustc 1.47.0-nightly
- Target is nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

What can cause maturin to fail with the above error message?

Comment: I feel like the key for solving this problem lies in the non-English text on the last line :) Perhaps `nicht finden` means "not found", as in `Cargo.toml.orig` is not found?

Comment: @DeepSpace it's the localized equivalent of "The system cannot find the file specified", afaik, though a file with a name like that feels like it might not be user-created

Comment: @Moira good, now OP just needs to find the specified file :)

Comment: FWIW, I found [one result for this error message](https://gitter.im/PyO3/Lobby?at=5ea23a61501f8f72a5fe75f6) and the poster stated that "it was an older version of maturin [they] had installed via pip."

Comment: The missing `Cargo.toml.orig` is definitely not the problem, because `maturin build` runs fine on Linux. It has something to do with the environment setup. But I cannot find out what could be the reason.

Comment: @Moira: I'm using the same latest version 0.8.2 of maturin on Linux and Windows.

Comment: I've found out that `maturin build --no-sdist` runs fine on Windows. So the problem is solved. But I still have no idea why `maturin build` fails on Windows and runs fine on Linux. `Cargo.toml.orig` does not exist, neither on Linux nor on Windows.

Comment: I found [this pull request](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin/pull/271) (which, for some reason doesn't show up in search results for the error message, as [someone else](https://github.com/PyO3/maturin/pull/271#issuecomment-592808639) pointed out), but this seems to have been merged months ago, so I'm not sure why you're having issues with the latest version.